# Overwriting values in a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I have the following code, where book is an array of structures and alpha, beta . . are members of the struct:

```
 for(i = 0; i < sizeof(book)/sizeof(book[0]); ++i) {
    n    = book[i].alpha;
    m    = book[i].beta;
    gnm  = book[i].gamma;
    hnm  = book[i].delta;
    dgnm = book[i].epsilon;
    dhnm = book[i].zeta;        
}
```

I want to use this to store the data that I have in a structure array into the variables n,m,..etc.  Right now this code only stores the last line of data into each variable.  How can I change this code so that the value isn't overwritten each time? eg instead of just storing 12 it should be 123456789101112.

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{ 
int i,n,m,floot;
int aplha[90],beta[90], buf_size = 3500, offset = 0;
float gnm,hnm,dgnm,dhnm,gamma[90],delta[90],epsilon[90],zeta[90];
static char  c_str[90]; 

    struct wmm
       {
        int   alpha;
        int   beta;
        float gamma;
        float delta;
        float epsilon;
        float zeta;
       }book[]= {
  {1, 0, -29496.6,       0.0,       11.6,       0.0},
  {1, 1,  -1586.3,    4944.4,       16.5,     -25.9},
  {2, 0,  -2396.6,       0.0,      -12.1,       0.0},
  {2, 1,   3026.1,   -2707.7,       -4.4,     -22.5},
  {2, 2,   1668.6,    -576.1,        1.9,     -11.8},

[...50 or so similar lines omitted...]

 {12, 11,    -0.8,      -0.2,       -0.1,        0.0},
 {12, 12,     0.0,       0.9,        0.1,        0.0}
 };
```

Comment: please post book structure code

Comment: What are your data types?  You'll want to append the values, not just assign them.

Comment: Giving the structure definition of `book` would be helpful. When you say you want to store `123456789101112` is that as a string, as a number or something else?

Comment: do you want `delta` ... I mean `hnm` to end up with `0.04944.40.0 ... -0.9-0.20.9`? It needs to be a char array (and so do all the other n, m, ... variables)

Comment: You can't do that with the data types you've listed (appending to `int`s and `float`s instead of strings or arrays).  You could do that with the arrays you've listed, and in that case you'd have something like `alpha[i] = book[i].alpha;`.  I still have no idea what you're trying to do with this; it seems absolutely pointless to me.

Comment: @David: To say nothing of the difficulty of later decoding the appended data, even if it was a valid operation.  I think the crucial question here is 'why'.

Comment: if you follow this link it explains why I would like to do this. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155647/storing-data-in-a-program-instead-of-in-an-external-file)

Comment: @officerkrupke:  If you have the array of structs, you already have the data readily available.  If you don't, you can't run this code.  Translating it into an impossible-to-decode format that won't fit in the data type specified won't change that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store them in such a way that it appends the data.  This can either be done with some kind of string object, or an array.  I'm not sure what your data type here is so I can't give an exact example, but the idea is to avoid repetitive assignment like that, as that will just override the previous value each iteration of the loop

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the operation you are using to store data.  Right now you are using the assignment ('=') operation which will overwrite whatever information was previously stored in your archiving variables.

Instead, you want to replace this with an appropriate append function.  For string data this probably means concatenation, for integer data, you are looking at something complicated enough that I would suggest first converting it to a string, and then storing a concatenation of that data.

So your loop would look something like:

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(book)/sizeof(book[0]); ++i)
  {
     append(&n, book[i].alpha);
     append(&m, book[i].beta);     
     append(&gnm, book[i].gamma);
     append(&hnm, book[i].delta);
     append(&dgnm, book[i].epsilon);
     append(&dhnm, book[i].zeta);
  }
```

Where `append` is a procedure you define to perform the appropriate work for your data type.

Alternately, I suppose you could turn your storage variables into arrays of the appropriate type and simply assign incoming data to the matching index into those arrays, e.g. `n[i] = book[i].alpha`, but that may be redundant given that you already have an array of structs storing that data for you.

Comment: This seems like it would work out but I don't understand what procedure I would write for ' append '

Comment: @officerkrupke: That makes two of us.  If you look at the comments on your original post, David Thornley makes the poimt that there is not a clearly valid way to append floats and ints.  If you can tell us what you need to do with the concatenated data it might be possible to suggest an option.

Comment: with some help from others on this site I realized that the original for loop that I had would work has long as the for loop included all of my calculations in it as well.  Thank you for your help!